# IFTTT Webhook not triggering

Tags: automation, webhooks, ifttt

I have the following applet:

[Applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iOP8.png)

It reads "If Maker Event "event1", then Send a notification from the IFTTT app". Then, I go to [https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/event1/with/key/[key]](https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/event1/with/key/%5Bkey%5D) and it reads

"Congratulations! You've fired the event1 event"

However, I never get the notification. I have waited 10 minutes, run manual checks, but still nothing. I've tried three variations of the event name, none of which work.

Is the Webhook service down or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Answered! I was using the wrong key. For anyone with this problem, try gonig to IFTTT > Connections > Webhooks > and go to the link

Comment: A little additional info. I had the same problem. I could fix it by retrieving a new key from the webhook settings page. Keep in mind that you need to replace the key in all your scripts, etc. But I dont think this should happen if it works once.
Here you can get a new key (klick on edit).
https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks/settings

Comment: This answer works for me, thanks. Also you can find this solution in IFTTT FAQ page (https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010230347-Webhooks-service-FAQ). But this is terrible, there is no sign for the old key to tell if it has any issue, and just then after I generated the new key, it works as usual.